# Use of Fubini's theorem to check if equalities holds

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I'm working on the following problem.

Would you check if my solution makes sense? I feel like I need more details in my argument. I don't know if it suffices.

> **Problem:**
>
> Let $D = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid -1 \leq x, y \leq 1\}$, and let $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the following function:
>
> $$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^5-y^5}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } x \neq 0 \text{ or } y \neq 0 \\ +\infty & \text{if } x = y = 0 \end{cases}$$
>
> Do the following equalities hold?
> $$\int_D f d\lambda^2 = \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 f(x,y) d\lambda(x) d\lambda(y) = \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 f(x,y) d\lambda(y) d\lambda(x)$$

---

**My attempt**:

Use Fubini's theorem: if a function is integrable over a product space, then its iterated integrals are also integrable and yield the same result as the full integral.

In this case, since the function is integrable over $D$, Fubini's theorem applies and we can interchange the order of integration without changing the value of the integral.

Therefore, we would get:

$\int_D f d\lambda^2 $ to be equal to the double integral from $-1$ to $1$ over $f(x,y)\lambda(x)\lambda(y)$ which would be equal to the double integral from $-1$ to $1$ over $f(x,y)\lambda(y)\lambda(x)$

Comment: Your definition of $f$ has a problem. You say$f : D\rightarrow \mathbb R$, but $f(0,0) = +\infty\notin \mathbb R$. Any particular reason for the choice $+\infty$?

Comment: I don't know, it's from the problem. I guess I just understand it as, when we are dealing with Lebesgue integrals, we can work with functions the Riemann integral can't integrate?

Answer (score 1):

The bulk of the work here is in proving that $f$ is integrable over the product space! Concretely, this amounts to proving that
$$ \int_D |f| d\lambda^2 < \infty.$$
You haven't done this.

My suggestion would be to redefine the value of $f$ $(0, 0)$ to be $0$, rather than $\infty$. Since $\{ (0, 0) \}$ is a set of measure zero, redefining $f$ in this way won't affect our conclusions.

My recommended next steps would be to:

- Show that $f$ is continuous on $D$, including at the point $(0, 0)$.
- Deduce that $f$ is bounded on $D$. (Think about what you know about the image of a continuous function on a compact space.)
- Deduce that $\int_D |f| d\lambda^2 < \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I've probably misunderstood something, but isn't the point of Lebesgue integrals that we can integrate functions, that the Riemann integral can't? I don't understand why just can redefine f(0,0) to be zero.

Comment: Ah, great question. The terminology is very confusing. A "measurable" function is a function that can be integrated. An "integrable" function is a function such that the integral of its norm is _finite_. If it was up to me, I would call measurable functions integrable and I would call integrable functions normable. But I didn't invent the terminology.

Comment: Redefining $f(0,0)$ doesn't affect the value of $\int_D |f| d\lambda^2$ because the singleton set $\{(0,0)\}$ is a null set. The original $f$ is integrable if and only if the redefined $f$ is integrable.

Comment: I think the polar coordinate expression is useful. $(x^5 - y^5)/(x^2 + y^2) = r^3 (\cos^5\theta - \sin^5\theta)$. Since $0 < r \le \sqrt{2}$, $|f(x,y)| \le 4\sqrt{2}$ if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$, and then the integral is finite.

Comment: Yes indeed, the polar representation is useful. One can also use the polar representation to show that (the redefined) $f$ is continuous at the origin.